# How to make an adjustment on User Profile page in Community Builder

Tags: template-override, view, layout, community-builder

I have a Joomla 3.9.26 site with CB 2.6.0 installed.

I need to make some little update on the User Profile page.

This is the url of the page:

```
index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userProfile&user=1382&Itemid=166&stp=1
```

or also

```
index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userProfile&user=1382&Itemid=166&stp=0
```

Which php file do I have to edit?
Consider also that the changes to the layout are based on the "stp" parameter in the query string. So how can I get its value inside the layout template?

Comment: Welcome Matt, please pick up a few quick badges here.  Take the [tour] and introduce yourself by editing your profile.  If you want the community to know who you are and your experience with Joomla, your profile is a good place to park that info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Community Builder myself so I can only give you some general tips.

What you could do to find the right page to edit:

- create a backup of your site (e.g. using Akeeba Backup) with files + database
- install that backup on your local computer (e.g. using XAMPP or something similar as web environment)
- visit your website in your browser and go to the page that you want to change
- in your browser look at the HTML of that page and determine a part (HTML tags) that is unique for the page (e.g. `<span id="user-profile">`).
- use an IDE (like PHPStorm, Eclipse, Netbeans, Visual Studio or something similar) that has good code search functionality
- use your IDE to search your local site for that unique text. Check the found files for that code.
- Make a small temporary (change it back to original later!) change in the file and check in your browser if you see that change on the page. If so, you have identified the file to edit.

General tips:

- don't change the component files. Core hacks can get lost with updates. Instead create template overrides (if the component supports it) https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core
- create an SQL export of your site. Put that SQL file in the root of your local site. If you are looking for something that is not in the files, it might be in the database. Never put that SQL dump on your server.